# Take backup of mysql from crash xampp?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem.
In my local i installed xampp. Suddenly it's crashed and I need all the database of my local mysql.

So is there any way to get all the Databases.

Comment: If you are using MySAMI tables, you can copy the files from the mysql folder, but if you are using InnoDB, it will be a bit harder to do. Either way, you need to add in some extra detail about *the crash* and what is actually happening. Does it work, does it start, are you getting (and what) errors when you try to start it?

Comment: actully My xampp is working but my MYSQL is stop working and don't start.
and not start

Comment: edited: since you said you cant startup mysql. Can you start the service in a terminal and give us the error it returns?

Comment: Of course, the alternative option is to figure out why your MySQL isn't working, and to fix that

Comment: when I start xampp controll panel and start Mysql services so it show me an error given below.
`mysqld.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.`

Comment: Have you looked in the mysql error log (probably found in /xampp/mysql/data/mysql_error.log) to see if that has recorded anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to jsut copy the folder containing the databases and try to open those in another XAMPP Instance

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the database folders from data folder and delete xampp then install it again 
Then for your innodb databases you need to rebuild the mysql log files by deleting the 
 ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1 files from the data folder and put innodb_log_file_size = 170M
In my.ini file then start mysql and it'll rebuild the log files

You can see my question about the same problem [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/lost-tables-in-drupal-site-database)

**Note:** remember to backup all your files and folders from the htdocs folder before you uninstall xampp

Comment: the excat database what I want it contain only .frm tables. There is no data related .MYI or .MYD.
So it's not show any data.

Comment: It means that your database uses the innodb engine so you have to rebuild the logs after copying the database folder to data folder so mysql can retrieve the data